# Load another page from jQuery popup and go to a specific section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a task where a user logs in, some text is shown to the user in a popup. the text has links which are different sections of the terms & conditions page. upon clicking the links, the terms page should load in that popup and go to that specific section. Any idea how this can be achieved.

```
jQuery(function (cash) {
    var test = true;
    loadTerms();
    $('.readMore').live("click", function () {
        test = false;
        loadTerms();
    });
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
        escClose: false,
        close: false,
        closeClass: 'simplemodal-close'
    });

    function loadTerms() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/AboutUs/terms/index.html',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html) {
                var div = jQuery('#marketing', jQuery(html));
                if (test) {
                    var myText = div.html().slice(0, 1100);
                    jQuery('.terms_content').html(myText + '<a href="javascript:void(o);" class="readMore"> ...Read More</a>');
                } else {
                    jQuery('.terms_content').html(div);
                    jQuery('.tc_link').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
                    var position = jQuery('.simplemodal-container').position();
                    jQuery('.simplemodal-container').animate({
                        width: "942",
                        height: "600",
                        top: position.top / 2,
                        left: position.left / 2
                    }, "fast");
                    jQuery('.terms_content').animate({
                        height: "530px"
                    }, "fast");
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Still now what you have tried? can you please post your code here?

Comment: Why you used `cash` in `jQuery(function (cash) {`?

Comment: its someone elses code and i need to make the changes that i mentioned above. i an not that good with jquery.. sorry